# asp.net core 6 with react does not run on same server

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I was using asp core 5 in which react and asp.net backend was running on same server
and now I want to make project in asp.net core 6 with react same as 5 but in 6 it does not run on same server and when go to production only the backend runs

Need Help...
how to make it run on same server

backend runs on https://localhost:7228/

and frontend runs on http://localhost:3000/

Comment: ? What is this question? There isn't even an isolated problem. Maybe just google a tutorial for deploying an application.

Comment: forget deploying while running only it creates two port in version 5 of visual studio 2019 it was running on same server but in 2022 its not

Comment: @nbokmans can suggest the tutorial been searching but got nothing